# Clicking specific class to trigger drop down event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How can I fix this? I have used php to display data from my database but I didn't foresee this bug.
When I click the gear icon both dropdown menu will appear. How can I fix this? What I want is when I click the gear of a specific project only one dropdown will appear. I hope you can help me its been bugging me for days. Thank you!!

[image: Please see the image here]

Here is my code:

***PHP CODE:***

```
if ($level == "Level 1"){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM project";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                if ($count > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "<input type='hidden' id='".$row['project_id']."'>";

                        echo "<div class='col-3'>";
                        echo "<div class='card'>";
                        echo "<div class='row'>";
                        echo "<div class='col-2'>";
                        echo "<h6 class='card-title'>".$row['project_name']."</h6>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='col-2'>";
                        echo "<div class='card-setting'><i class='fa fa-gear'></i></div>";
                        echo "<div id='card-setting-dropdown' class='card-dropdown-content'>";
                        echo "<button class='card-dropdown-menu' id='delete_project'>Delete Project</button>";
                        echo "<button class='card-dropdown-menu' id='add_task'>Add Task</button>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='row'>";
                        echo "<div class='col-2'>";
                        echo "<label  class='project-details'>".$row['department']."</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='col-2'>";
                        echo "<label class='project-details' style='float:right;'>Priority: ".$row['priority']."</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='pr-task-data'>";
                        echo "<div class='pr-task-summary-l'>";
                        echo "<label class='pr-task-title'>Tasks</label>";
                        echo "<p class='pr-task-details'>12</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='pr-task-summary-l'>";
                        echo "<label class='pr-task-title'>Completed</label>";
                        echo "<p class='pr-task-details'>5</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='pr-task-summary-l'>";
                        echo "<label class='pr-task-title'>In-Progress</label>";
                        echo "<p class='pr-task-details'>2</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='pr-task-summary-r'>";
                        echo "<label class='pr-task-title'>Not Completed</label>";
                        echo "<p class='pr-task-details'>5</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='progress'>";
                        echo "<div class='progress-bar'>";
                        echo "<label class='progress-bar-percent'>50%</label>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                }
            }
```

***Script:***

```
//Card-Settings Dropdown
$(".card-setting").click(function() {
    $(".card-dropdown-content").toggleClass("card-dropdown-content-show");
    $(this).toggleClass("card-setting-active");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the script activates you toggle the class car-dropdown-content-show for all cards. You should only focus on the one inside the card and find the one with the card-dropdown-content class:

```
$(".card-setting").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().find(".card-dropdown-content").toggleClass("card-dropdown-content-show");
    $this.toggleClass("card-setting-active");
});
```

We first need to go up to the parent because the find looks through all the descendants, the div with the card-dropdown-content class is a sibling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find related element to clicked gear.

Try this:

```
$('.card-setting').on('click', function () {
   var $this = $(this) ;

   $this.next().toggleClass("card-dropdown-content-show");
   $this.toggleClass("card-setting-active");
});
```